# ubuntu 16.04LTS freezing system + TTY

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, lvm, tty

I'm running Lenovo YOGA 300-IBY, Ubuntu 16.04LTS
here is my first problem: whenever I open my TTY <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd>, there are lines:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4128768: Input/output error
/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4186112: Input/output error
/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 309609/3629056 files, 2950306/14516224 blocks
```

And I cant type there to log in.

My second problem is about freezing, my notebook has random freeze and not even REISUB is helping, it doesn't respond to anything and I have to hard restart.

Comment: Looks like the flash storage in your laptop is either broken internally or there's a bug in its driver in Linux. I recommend that you boot from a live DVD/USB and perform the “basic” and “read-only” checks from [this answer](/a/539185/175814) on the internal flash storage device before we continue. Save and submit any error messages to us please. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So here it is:

### BASIC

> sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/null count=1

`1+0 records in`

`1+0 records out`

`512 bytes copied, 0,000xx s, 1,9MB/s`

### READ-ONLY CHECK

> sudo badblocks -b 4096 -c 4096 -s /dev/mmcblk0

`checking for bad blocks (read-only test)" 0,00% done, 0:00 elapse (0/0/0 error) done`